# Trouble sending checkbox values with php and javascript Ajax

Tags: php, javascript

I am having some trouble diplaying the values of my checkboxes in the email my form sends, I am using html form field that uses php and javascript Ajax to send the email. If I leave the code form Javascript out then all the values display as Yes and with the code it displays No. I'm new to php and would appreciate any help. Thanks.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="test.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
<input name="extension" type="checkbox" id="extension" value="extension">Extension<br>
<input name="wallmount" type="checkbox" id="wallmount" value="wallmount">Wall Mount<br>
<input name="deskmount" type="checkbox" id="deskmount" value="deskmount">Desk Mount
</form>
```

PHP

```
$extension=($_POST['extension'])?"Extension: Yes":"Extension: No";
$wallmount=($_POST['wallmount'])?"Wallmount: Yes":"Wallmount: No";
$wallmount=($_POST['wallmount'])?"Wallmount: Yes":"Wallmount: No";
$deskmount=($_POST['deskmount'])?"Deskmount: Yes":"Deskmount: No";

$msg.="$extension";;
$msg.="$wallmount";;
$msg.="$deskmount";;
```

Javascipt

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('#contactform').submit(function(){

    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $('#contactform #submit').attr('disabled','disabled');

    $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
    $('#message').hide();           

    $.post(action, { 

            extension: $('#extension').serialize(),
        wallmount: $('#wallmount').serialize(),
        deskmount: $('#deskmount').serialize(),

        subject: $('#subject').val(),
        verify: $('#verify').val()
    },
        function(data){
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
            $('#message').slideDown('slow');
            $('#contactform #submit').attr('disabled',''); 
            if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

        }
    );

    });

    return false; 

});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including the value of every checkbox. You should test to see if it is checked or not.

More generally, you should let jQuery build your data object from your form for you.

```
$.post(action, $('form').serialize());
```

Comment: Thank for reply, do I need replaced the 'extension: $('#extension').val(),' with your code 'data: $('myformname').serialize()'?

Comment: Oh, didn't notice you were using $.post instead of $.ajax. The edit should fix it.

Comment: If I replace `$.post(action,` with your code I get a Syntax error

Comment: I edited the Javascript code with the full code, let me know if this helps

Comment: It doesn't include the change that I suggested that you say is causing the syntax error.

Comment: Sorry about that, I included it

Comment: You have two `$`s and you didn't remove the original attempt to include the data, you just shoved the replacement (the call to serialize) in front of it.

Comment: I updated the code, no syntex error but it does not validate anymore or sends

Comment: Thank you Quentin for your help. I got it working with the above code, just had to change the val with serialize. You ROCK!!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.post(action, { 
extension: $('#extension').attr('checked'),
wallmount: $('#wallmount').attr('checked'),
deskmount: $('#deskmount').attr('checked'),
},
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, the values still sends as Yes even if the boxes are not checked